# xkb utf8 symbols but no syms

Tags: keyboard, wayland, xkb, setxkbmap

Fedora 39 here, but this should apply in general for any linux.

My ~/.xkb/symbols/my has this (part):

```
    replace key <FK01> {
    [ F1, F1, {H,e,l,l,o}, {W,o,r,l,d}, XF86_Switch_VT_1 ]
    };
```

Where I redefine F1 key to produce "Hello" by pressing AltGr+F1 and "World" by pressing AltGr+Shift+F1.

And I load this layout and it does compile and it activates.

Under wayland **wev** says for the keypresses this:

```
    [14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 2666; time: 3375520; key: 67; state: 1 (pressed)
    sym: NoSymbol     (0), utf8: 'Hello'
    [14:     wl_keyboard] key: serial: 2674; time: 3378992; key: 67; state: 1 (pressed)
    sym: NoSymbol     (0), utf8: 'World'
```

Programs like Kate and Kwrite receive input "Hello" and "World", but programs like LibreOffice Writer, Chrome-Browse and Firefox do not.

My question is why the difference?